# How to use where() in a JSON column in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

In my Research table, I have a column 'author' that is casted into JSON. The reason I casted it, because Research and Author is many-to-many.

```
protected $cast =[
        'authors' => 'array'
    ];
```

Is there a way that I can parse data something like this:

```
$author = 1;
$data = Research::where('author', $author)->get();


"type"      "title"      "authors"
Thesis      WLAN yeah    ["1"]
Thesis      ELAW         ["11"]
```

Comment: Why did you opt for json instead of a standard many to many relationship?

Comment: Show a JSON sample to work with.

Comment: Laravel supports `where()` on JSON columns, like `where('meta->color', 'red')`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is a good practice, but you can do:

```
$data = Research::where('author', 'like', "\"%{$author}\"%")->get();
```